# Mysql cluster configuration help

Tags: mysql, clustering, mysql-cluster, ndbcluster

I am new to mysql cluster I was reading around the web how to set it up. I came up with 2 different set up not sure which one is better fail safe vs cost efficient. Our new site have clients in USA and Japan. We are not big site, and saving money is high priority for us.

V1)

US Servers, Japan Servers

```
Front End 3 servers
  Apache 
  local memcached + connects to mysql memcached 

Mysql cluster 
  One management node (This will be aware of japanese/us management node)
  Two data Nodes 
  Two Sql Nodes
```

V2)

US Servers, Japan Servers

```
Front End 3 servers
  Apache 
  local memcached + connects to mysql memcached 

Mysql cluster 
  One management node (This will be aware of japanese/us management node)
  Two data Nodes/ Sql Nodes combined
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is not a performance issue with having data and sql living on the same node, V2 will be viable and cheaper.

I generally do not like having caches in front of caches, so I question the need for memcached.